# FETCH specific number of primary key rows

Tags: sql-server

I have an SQL SELECT that left-joins several tables together, which results in an output with redundant data.

Example query:

```
SELECT 
A.ID, B.ID
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.ParentID=A.ID
FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY
```

Example output:

```
A.ID B.ID
1    10
1    20
2    30
2    40
```

My problem is that I want to limit the number of rows from the A table, not from the actual output. In short, I would like to have an output like this when I ask for 4 rows:

```
A.ID B.ID
1    10
1    20
2    30
2    40
3    50
3    60
4    70
4    80
```

Any advice?

UPDATE:
Here is a fiddle that could help explaining the problem:
[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/64cbb6/4)

Comment: Use a subquery to get only the top 4 from A, and then JOIN that to B

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible since the query could be filtered on columns from B, like ... WHERE B.City='Stockholm'

Comment: so filter the outer query, or put the filter in the JOIN condition. I don't see why that's a problem.

Comment: I guess you're right, @TabAlleman, but my situation is that the actual queries are generated by code, dynamically, and can be really complex. If possible, I'd like to keep the structure intact. The filters are also generated by code and constructed by the end user. That creates problems for filters in the JOIN condition when the user asks for something like A.Company='Acme' OR B.City='London'

Answer (score 0):

i have applied query on actual data, use sub query to get top 4 result.

```
declare @temp table
(aId int, bId int)

insert into @temp
values
(1,10),
(1,20),
(2,30),
(2,40),
(3,50),
(3,60),
(4,70),
(4,80),
(5,90),
(6,100)

select * from @temp
where aId in
(select distinct top 4 aId from @temp where aId > 1)
```

Comment: This subquery needs an order by unless it doesn't matter which 4 rows you will get. Without an order by there is no guarantee what rows come back.

Comment: Perhaps I was vague in my question. The ids are just an example and the order could be by any other column. I'll update my question to make this more clear